# Button change panels

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing a game and I want my panel to be changed with the next panel  by clicking a button [panelimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcRAw.png). What should I change in the script to change panels not scene?

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class MainMenuControl : MonoBehaviour
{

 public void changemenuscene (string scenename)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(scenename);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add some code of what you have so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "next panel" ? Do you have an array or list of panels somewhere?

Comment: Please add some code for more understandable what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `GameObjects` easy mode you can use `panel.SetActive(false)` or `true` to turn them on and off.